# What should be the foreign key that the client sends when creating a new record in a database?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, fastapi, pydantic

I am making a web application with python, fastapi and postgresql. Within the database there are two related entities: "departments" and "users", with a one-to-many relationship:

These are pydantic models:

```
# Shared properties
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    username: str | None = None
    email: EmailStr | None = None
    role: Roles | None = None

# Properties to receive via API on creation
class UserCreate(UserBase):
    username: str
    password: str
    role: Roles
    department_id: int # ???
```

Therefore, when a user is created in the application, a foreign key must be sent that points to the department to which the user belongs. By convention, this foreign key is the id(Pk) of the department, however I thought that perhaps when the client wants to create a new user, it will be difficult for him to remember the id of the department to which he wants to associate it.
How should I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by chance planning to use an ORM in your web app, something like [SQL Alchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html)?

If so, you may be able to model your solution from their examples.  The (many) item to User relationship in [this example](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D) may also be a good guide.  I'm less familiar with your particular stack than some others but hopefully this can be of a small help.

I'm constantly handed API-based integrations where I don't think the original creators actually considered the dependent needs of their designs, on behalf of your future API consumers - thank you for putting thought into this up front :)

Just brainstorming and in generality it is reasonable in API design when an attribute is required but is based on a look-up value from another table so long as you have get endpoints to allow your API Consumers to query those dependent entities.  You'd typically present your Departments in a some sort selection-list, anyway.

I've also seen developers lean on tags or codes (sort of like the PLU codes on fruit and veggies) for fast-Create, heavily repetitive UIs where users/staff are trained to enter values quickly and can enter the related field (in your case, department) but those were pretty specialized in terms of business requirements: like retail inventory counters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. Yes, I am actually using Tortoise-ORM. Thank you for your words about thinking about future consumers, sometimes we can't even get direct feedback from them :).
Definitely presenting the list of departments in a kind of selection list seems to me the best option. If I have another endpoint where I can get all the departments and even a specific one according to their name, will this be enough for this list to be built from the frontend? (I'm backend, and new of course hehe).

Comment: Yep, exactly! - so, in that case where you'd have a select list of departments populated from api call..  Something like.. 

(pseudo/ off the top of my head)
@app.get("/departments")
async def get_departments():
    return await job_pydantic.from_queryset(Departments.all())

Over on the API Consumer/ UI side of the house- the select list is populated from that call and the option values would be your department ids and the text enclosed would be the department name, the calls to UserCreate from that form would have in scope the department id by virtue of the selection.    Best of luck!